# I want to retrieve the confidence score of an intent in Dialogflow CX

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-cx

I want in Dialogflow CX that if an intent is recognized, I want to capture the confidence score of that utterence in a value of a parameter. I'll need it to create several conditional routes in all pages.

Dividing it by flows is not possible, because there are 140 intents involved and it will hit the limit of Dialogflow. Is there a (not so) technical solution for this? i've never created a webhook for example. And the systems around Dialogflow also make it hard to use other external programs.

In the end, in the picture at the ??? I want to have the confidence level

[image]

Comment: I found this one: $request.sentiment.score for the sentiment analysis. Is there something like this for the confidence score?